# How to change one variable value from CSV at the Recycle in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have CSV (Users.CSV)which contains 10000 Username, Firstname,LastName and Email ID which are unique. In one of the POST request in my test plan, I need to  pass date. I can POST data only once for same date. How i can handle this using CSV or any other way?

I can think of two options: 
1. Drag same date for all the 10000 entry in same Users.CSV. And then Copy paste Username, Firstname,LastName and Email ID again in same CSV and then drag next date. 
2. Maintain two CSV files, One for Users and one for Date. Date.csv will have 10000 entries for same date and after 10001 will contains next date.

On both the solutions i will need to maintain sample count as i will need to delete those many entries from CSV for the next run.

Can someone please share any better option to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two compoenent to resolve this issue:-

1. [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)
2. [BeanShell-PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor)

**Step 1:** Define a vraible in script using user definded variables to keep counter of date, so that same date should not be used aagain while making that particular POST request.

[image: UDV example]

**Step 2:** Use variable defined in step 1, and write script to get unique date in pre-processor. This pre-processor should be added as child to that particular POST request.

sample code for pre-processor:-

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

   int dateCounter=Integer.parseInt(vars.get("dateCounter")); 

   Date currentDate = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");


   long milliseconds = (long) dateCounter * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
   Date previousDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - milliseconds);
   String strDate = date.format(previousDate);
   vars.put("date",strDate);


   dateCounter  = dateCounter - 1;
   vars.put("dateCounter",Integer.toString(dateCounter));
```

Note that we are using last 1000 days in the example, you can make changes as per your need. Now this `date` -a Jmeter variable can be used through out the thread group and once you generate a date using that partilculare POST sampler, a new date would be generated for next request.

Answer (score 2):

Use [__time() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) to generate the current date (or combine it with [__longSum() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) if you need past/future timestamps)

By default `__time()` function returns current time in milliseconds since beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), however you can control the format using [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns.

[image: JMeter Time Function Examples]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on above two and other JMeter functions

Comment: Thanks for solutions. I am able to resolve my issue.